# How do I justify mathematically the following equality related to exponential r.v.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose you want to solve the following exercise: you are at a car wash and you launch a coin to decide what program to  use to wash your care. If you get head you pick the first service whose duration is distributed as an exponential random variable of parameter $1/8$. If you get tails you pick the second service whose duration is distributed as an exponential random variable of parameter $1/5$. What is the probability that your service (that you have not chosen yet launching the coin) will last more than 10 minutes?

Let $X$ be the r.v. which is $0$ when you get tails and $1$ when you get heads.

Call $T$ the r.v. representing the duration of the service. I want to compute $P(T>10)$ in the following way intuitively using the partition's formula:
\begin{align}
P(T>10)& =P(T>10|X=0)P(X=0)+P(T>10|X=1)P(X=1)\\
&=e^{-10/8}0.5+ e^{-10/5}0.5
\end{align}

How do I justify in a rigorous way that $P(T>10|X=0)=e^{-10/8}$ (and the other case) i.e. that the conditional law of $T$ is exponential ?

Comment: What has to be justified?  You assumed the exponential initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_0\sim\text{Exponential}(1/8)$ and $T_1\sim\text{Exponential}(1/5)$, and let $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ independently of $T_0$ and $T_1.$ Then $$T=\begin{cases}
T_0&\text{ if }X=0\\
T_1&\text{ if }X=1
\end{cases}$$
so
\begin{align}
P(T>10)
& =P(T>10\cap X=0)+P(T>10\cap X=1)\\[2mm]
& =P(T_0>10\cap X=0)+P(T_1>10\cap X=1)\tag{1}\\[2mm]
& =P(T_0>10)P(X=0)+P(T_1>10)P(X=1)\tag{2}\\[2mm]
&=e^{-10/8}0.5+ e^{-10/5}0.5
\end{align}
where (1) is because $\{T>10\cap X=0\}$ is the same event as $\{T_0>10\cap X=0\}$ (and similarly for the $X=1$ case), and (2) follows from independence.

Comment: ALternatively we have $P(T>10 |X=1)=P(T_0>10)$ right?

Comment: @carlos85 If you meant to write $P(T>10 |X=0)=P(T_0>10)$, then yes, that's true; but "justifying it in a rigorous way" -- i.e. applying the *definition* of the conditional probability -- requires the joint probabilities that I've indicated.